# specific device media queries are not working

Tags: css, media-queries

I am writing media queries to my slider. for that sider width is 100% and height should be given manually. Thats why I have written @media queries for every width like

```css
@media only screen and (width : 320px) and (height: 568px) {
.demo .zoomer_wrapper { height: 450px; }
}
@media only screen and (width : 568px) and (height: 320px) {
.demo .zoomer_wrapper { height: 230px; }
}
```

I am testing the resolutions in http://cybercrab.com/screencheck/ and firefox. Here every thing is working fine for every set of width and height. But when I checked in a particular device those are not working. Pls help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Media queries for phones and tablets should look like :

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 320px){}
```

> [Documentation](http://media-queries.aliasdmc.fr/media-queries-live.php)

---

*Edit*

Exemple (and only an exemple, not tested) :

```
/*if landscape*/
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 320px) and (orientation : landscape){
    .demo .zoomer_wrapper { height: 230px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 800px) and (orientation : landscape){
    .demo .zoomer_wrapper { height: 710px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 960px) and (orientation : landscape){
    .demo .zoomer_wrapper { height: 870px; }
}    
/*if portrait*/
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 320px) and (orientation : portrait){
    .demo .zoomer_wrapper { height: 230px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 480px) and (orientation : portrait){
    .demo .zoomer_wrapper { height: 390px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait){
    .demo .zoomer_wrapper { height: 530px; }
}
```

Comment: Hello Eden.. Thnx for the reply.. But I dont want to use max and min becuase if I use them they are conflicting.. for example

Comment: I'am sorry, but to aim at particular devices, you have to use `max/min-device-width`.  You have to organise your rules conditions in order that it must not have any conflict. For exemple, start with the lower height rule, and then the next higher height, and the next one, to reach the final biggest height value. See updated answer

Comment: Thnx Eden. Hope any one got the answer.. and I want to target specific device resolution...